# How can i get String with Static object position from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

---

I need to get String from only first position on this movies array

only title "Star wars" on first position

but my code it's return null

---

```
{
title: "The Basics - Networking",
description: "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
movies: [
{
title: "Star Wars",
releaseYear: "1977"
},
{
title: "Back to the Future",
releaseYear: "1985"
},
{
title: "The Matrix",
releaseYear: "1999"
},
{
title: "Inception",
releaseYear: "2010"
},
{
title: "Interstellar",
releaseYear: "2014"
}
]
}
```

---

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    xName: '',
  };

}
```

---

```
componentDidMount() {
     fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => 
        {this.setState({xName: responseJson.title[0]});})
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })

  alert(this.state.xName);
}
```

---

but my alert is return null of xName . it's can't set state from title

Comment: haven't tested it but may be try this `responseJson.movies[0].title`

Comment: it's return null again :(

Comment: `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` so may be try outside the` componentDidMount`  like inside your `render` method.

Comment: what ? setState can work ...
it's work on my code from setState on componentDidMount and work on <text>{this.state.xName}</text>
but on alert can't work it's return null of xName

https://snack.expo.io/SkNlE7vUZ

Comment: did i say `setState` doesn't work? Like i said  `setState()` does not immediately mutate(update) state, calling this.state after the `setState` method may return existing value. you can read more about it here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
 class movieFetch extends Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {movies: ''};
        }

    componentDidMount() {
         fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {this.setState({movies: responseJson.title});})
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }

    render(){
        return (
          alert({this.state.movies[0].title}),
          <h3>{this.state.movies[0].title}</h3>
        );
    }
```

Comment: @boy_v answered two of your question, haven't accepted them as answer yet? please,  if it solved your problem mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Star Wars title, you need to get `responseJson.movies[0].title` instead of `responseJson.title[0]`

Comment: IS your api returning any data?

Comment: change your fetch block to this
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
         {movies: json.movies[0].title}
        });

      });
  }

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/r1SeS7PUZ

it's work on render.
but alert can't work.

Comment: :). You are not rendering it the right way. Read a tutorial on React, asking questions won't help you understand

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html here is a good starting point